# Custom picture on lock screen

Tags: mac, macos, login-screen

So, I have been looking up online about how to put a custom picture on the lock screen that is not blurred. All of the tutorials online have said to change the "com.apple.desktop.admin.png" file in the /Library/Caches/ directory. This only changes the picture on the LOGIN screen when you boot up the Mac. Is there any way to put a picture on the lock screen that is not blurred. I am running El Capitan. Let me know if you need any more info. Thanks for your help in advance. :)

Comment: Seems to work for me in Yosemite. Could be that they changed it. In yosemite they both use this image.

Comment: @Joonas it's odd... it somehow works for the login screen but not the lock screen.